# Truncating ciphertexts on ring-LWE schemes

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, post-quantum-cryptography

On the section 5.4 of the paper [Improved Security for a Ring-Based Fully Homomorphic Encryption Scheme](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/075), the authors explain how to discard some bits of the ciphertexts to get smaller ciphertexts and smaller evaluation keys.

The function *Discard* simply takes a ciphertext $c$ and an integer $i$ (number of words to be discarded) and returns

$\lfloor w^{-i}c \rfloor$

where $w$ is the number of bits of each word.

But, since $c$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients (coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_q$), I don't understand how this function is discarding bits. To me, it seems like it is only zeroing all the coefficients whose absolute values are smaller than $w^i$.

I also checked the reference from where this technique of truncating ciphertext was extracted, named the paper [Fully Homomorphic Encryption without Modulus Switching from Classical GapSVP](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/078), but its explanation does not make sense to me as well.

So, do you know how this technique works? Could you give more details or show me what point I am interpreting wrong?

Comment: AFAIK, coefficients of $c$ are in $\mathbb Z_q$, therefore $\lfloor w^{-i}c \rfloor$ is actually $\lfloor ((w^i)^{-1} \bmod q) \cdot c \rfloor$.

Comment: Yes, sure, you are right, the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}_q$, not in $\mathbb{Z}$. I was not very precise.

Comment: Anyway, it does not make sense yet, does it? Because multiplying each coefficient by some inverse modular will not discard bits...

Comment: You are right. Forget what I said :P

Comment: By the way I don't think this multiplication is done as you said, because if it was the case, all the results would be in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and it would be pointless to take the floor... But thanks, @cygnusv    :)

Comment: Suppose that $w=2$. Then $\lfloor w^{-i}c \rfloor$ is equivalent to right-shifting $i$ bits of $c$ (i.e., dropping the last $i$ bits). I guess the same principle applies for an arbitrary $w$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression $c' = \lfloor w^{-i} c \rfloor$ is a slight abuse of notation. What it technically means is to interpret each coefficient of $c$ as real number, divide by $w^i$, round the result to the nearest integer, and then interpret it as an element of $\mathbb{Z}_q$ again.

This is equivalent to expressing each $\mathbb{Z}_q$ coefficient of the ciphertext as a bitstring, and then discarding the $i$ least significant $w$-words of each bitstring. It also explains why $w^i c'$ is equal to c with the $i$ least significant $w$-words of $c$ being set to $0$, as the authors say in the next sentence of Section 5.4.

By the way, $w$ does not represent the number of bits in each word. Instead, $w$ describes the *size* of each word, and so the number of bits in each word is actually $log_2(w)$.

If you're interested in other examples of where the technique of discarding the lower-order bits is used, see works on the [Learning with Rounding problem](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/098.pdf). (The paragraph in the middle of page 2 gives an equivalent explanation of this notation.)

Comment: So, in order to recover the original message $m$ from the new ciphertext $c'$ do we have to decrypt $w^i \cdot c'$ ?